# How to remove marks from screen

Tags: cleaning, stain

I had my calculator and santizer bottle in the same pocket of my bag. The bottle leaked and the sanitizer spilled over the calculator screen, leaving the marks on the screen as shown in the picture. Is there some way to clear the screen?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The sanitizer has dissolved the acreen.  You'll have to grind off the top layer and repolish.

Comment: Any tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend trying a headlight restoration polish. It is designed for plastics and you simply rub it with a microfiber cloth.

If that fails, try a Mr. Clean Magic Eraser or equivalent. They work because they are essentially high grit sandpaper. Use it **very gently** on the part that says Casio and verify that it is working as expected before doing the whole screen.